# Modal dialog based on Ionic and AngularJS leads to freezing the app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, xcode, ionic-framework

I took over a project with AngularJS, Ionic and Cordova (plugins).

Due to another problem, I had to update my infrastructure (including an update to XCode 7.2.1), which looks like the following now:

*npm list -g --depth=0*

```
├── bower@1.7.7
├── cordova@6.0.0
├── grunt-cli@0.1.13
├── grunt-sass@1.1.0
├── ionic@1.7.14
├── ios-deploy@1.8.5
├── ios-sim@5.0.6
├── n@2.1.0
├── to@0.2.9
└── update@0.4.2
```

*npm list --depth=0*

```
├── cordova@6.0.0
├── grunt@0.4.5
├── grunt-angular-templates@0.5.9
├── grunt-autoprefixer@0.4.2
├── grunt-bump@0.3.4
├── grunt-cli@0.1.13 extraneous
├── grunt-concurrent@0.4.3
├── grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0
├── grunt-contrib-concat@0.3.0
├── grunt-contrib-connect@0.5.0
├── grunt-contrib-copy@0.4.1
├── grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.7.0
├── grunt-contrib-htmlmin@0.1.3
├── grunt-contrib-jshint@0.7.2
├── grunt-contrib-uglify@0.2.7
├── grunt-contrib-watch@0.5.3
├── grunt-conventional-changelog@1.2.2
├── grunt-githooks@0.3.1
├── grunt-htmlhint@0.4.1
├── grunt-jscs@1.5.0
├── grunt-newer@0.6.1
├── grunt-ng-annotate@0.2.3
├── grunt-ng-constant@0.5.0
├── grunt-ngdocs@0.2.9
├── grunt-sass@1.1.0
├── grunt-usemin@2.0.2
├── grunt-wiredep@1.7.1
├── ionic@1.7.14
├── jshint-stylish@0.1.5
├── load-grunt-tasks@0.2.1
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── node-sass@3.4.2
└── time-grunt@0.2.10
npm ERR! extraneous: grunt-cli@0.1.13
```

*cordova platform version*

```
Installed platforms: android 4.1.1, ios 4.0.1
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, osx, webos
```

*cordova plugin list*

```
cc.fovea.cordova.purchase 4.0.0 "Purchase"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.5.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.2-dev "StatusBar"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.8 "Keyboard"
```

Now when i.e. jumping into a "saving-function" based on JavaScript, the app stalls and the modal dialog is not hiding anymore. Here is some sample code:

**HTML**

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <a class="button button-icon icon ion-checkmark-circled" ng-click="save()"></a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$scope.save = function () 
{
 if ($scope.dosomething.length < 1) 
 {
   $scope.$emit('toast', 'Do not do this!');
   return;
 }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cordova-ionic 4.1.0-dev was the "solution". More can be seen [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/193#issuecomment-187152531).

Comment: Nice. I was told this is a smart community. However this question and a bunch of other questions I asked recently s had not been answered. But as soon as I go the extra mile (which I am not "supposed" to do imho) and answer my own question to provide value-add to the community, people jump in right away to let me know what they expect from me in being more detailed...